# HTML5 video tag not showing thumbnail on mobile Safari

Tags: html, html5-video, vimeo

I am trying to embed a Vimeo video on my website:

```
        <video id="home-video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true">
            <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/XXX.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
            <source src="http://www.mywebsite.com/XXX.webm" type="video/webm">    
            <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/XXX.jpeg">
        </video>
```

This works great on HTML5 supporting browsers, but in mobile safari (iPhone), since the video is not automatically played, a thumbnail of the video is expected to be displayed. Instead, I only get a black square. 
After play/pause of the movie on mobile, the thumbnail is displayed correctly.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't want to use a poster attribute since on autoplay it flickers.

Comment: well you know autoplay videos can ruin User Experience...
Never had issue with poster attribute. But try it with a `.png` image.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `.jpg` image to `.png` and it will work.

I had this issue and since then I use `.png` to posters inside `<video>` tag, because `.png` posters work on every browser.